# Prove using the formal definition of a limit that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x+\sqrt 7}{x^3 + x^2}=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I know that given $K>0$ we must search for $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|>k$ when $|x|<\delta$ but cannot come up with an entire proof.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1):

Because $x\to 0$ we can assume $|x| < \frac{1}{3}$ hence $$\frac{3x+\sqrt 7}{x^3 + x^2} \ge \frac{\sqrt{7} - 1}{x^3 + x^2} \ge \frac{1}{2x^2}$$

The rest you can do by your own?